# convert favicon.ico to png in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

is there a way to save a website's favicon.ico file as a png in xcode?

For example:

http://www.google.com/favicon.ico

Comment: I can think about little method that can get it to the point, but as I understand you mean some menu/file/save as option. I think that there's no such option in XCode.

Comment: figured it out. UIImageView can display ico files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search Google for online converter .ico to .png.

http://www.convertico.com/ has something, for example.